# react POST form fetch

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native component with  form and I want to send and delete data on the id. Now I can not send the form, I use the Fetch POST and sumbit the data
 to the JSON format with the date name for example {data: {name: 'test name'}}

what I missed, here is my code
and if it's not difficult to describe or give a link to the article how to delete on the id

```
class NewRecord extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        address: ''
    };

    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePhoneChange = this.handlePhoneChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAddressChange = this.handleAddressChange.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        phone: this.state.phone,
        address: this.state.address
    };

    if (this.state.name !== '' && this.state.phone !== '' && this.state.address !== '') {
        console.log('name', this.state.name, 'phone ', this.state.phone, 'address ', this.state.address);

        fetch("example.com/:id", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            mode: "cors",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

    } else {
        alert('no')
    }
}

handleNameChange(event) {
    console.log('handleNameChange', this);
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
}

handlePhoneChange(event) {
    console.log('handleNameChange', this);
    this.setState({phone: event.target.value});
}

handleAddressChange(event) {
    console.log('handleNameChange', this);
    this.setState({address: event.target.value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <form className='form__row' method='POST' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="NAME"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleNameChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="PHONE"
                value={this.state.phone}
                onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="ADDRESS"
                value={this.state.address}
                onChange={this.handleAddressChange}
            />
            <button type='submit'>save</button>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Include the error you are getting. Saying you're not able to "send the form" is very vague.

Comment: Unexpected end of JSON input in console and 204 from backend

Answer (score 0):

try to take out

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

and just log the straight response to the console.

```
.then(response => console.log(response))
```

Perhaps, you could specify also what line your getting the error thrown by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving a HTTP code of 204 from the server you can't call `response.json()` since there is no content to parse! Instead just check for `response.ok` if you want to check if the request was successfull

Comment: Welcome @ChristianHehlBM on StackOverflow, It would be really helpful if you add some reference code with your answer. For more detail please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer